# debug websocket++ broadcast_server.cpp ('owner_less' is not a member of 'std')

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, std, member, websocket++

Zaphoyd's `broadcast_server.cpp` looks like the perfect backbone for a websocket server that it can quickly accept and send messages & connections with a thread for the real action so not to interrupt the communications.  https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp

His simple `print_server.cpp` example compiles easily; however, I'm getting a few compile errors with `broadcast_server.cpp`.

```
root@server:~# g++ -O3 broadcast_server.cpp -I ~/websocketpp-experimental/ -lboost_system
broadcast_server.cpp:126:37: error: 'owner_less' is not a member of 'std'
broadcast_server.cpp:126:37: error: 'owner_less' is not a member of 'std'
broadcast_server.cpp:126:70: error: 'con_list' was not declared in this scope
broadcast_server.cpp:126:70: error: template argument 2 is invalid
broadcast_server.cpp:126:18: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in this declaration [enabled by default]
broadcast_server.cpp:129:5: error: 'con_list' does not name a type
broadcast_server.cpp: In member function 'void broadcast_server::process_messages()':
broadcast_server.cpp:109:17: error: 'm_connections' was not declared in this scope
broadcast_server.cpp:112:17: error: 'm_connections' was not declared in this scope
broadcast_server.cpp:116:17: error: 'con_list' has not been declared
broadcast_server.cpp:116:36: error: expected ';' before 'it'
broadcast_server.cpp:117:22: error: 'it' was not declared in this scope
broadcast_server.cpp:117:27: error: 'm_connections' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm new to c++, and these are probably simple issues, but I can't find my way through them.

`'owner_less' is not a member of 'std'`?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/owner_less

I'm guessing that the `template argument 2` `error` will go away when the above is solved.

`'con_list' was not declared in this scope` when it's right there in the `private:`?  same with `'m_connections'`?

I'm guessing that `'con_list' has not been declared` will go away when the above error does.

I don't know which `'it'` it's talking about or why it should have a `;` in front of it.

**versions**

Ubuntu 12.10

`gcc --version` `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2`

boost 1.53.0

**extra `#include`s**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
```

still nothing

**`-std=c++11`**

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/map:60:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_ymd.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_calendar.hpp:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/common/thread.hpp:41,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/concurrency/basic.hpp:31,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/config/core.hpp:35,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp:31,
                 from broadcast_server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of 'class std::_Rb_tree<boost::weak_ptr<void>, boost::weak_ptr<void>, std::_Identity<boost::weak_ptr<void> >, std::owner_less<boost::weak_ptr<void> >, std::allocator<boost::weak_ptr<void> > >':
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_set.h:116:17:   required from 'class std::set<boost::weak_ptr<void>, std::owner_less<boost::weak_ptr<void> > >'
broadcast_server.cpp:132:14:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_tree.h:471:31: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::owner_less<boost::weak_ptr<void> >'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/memory:87,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/time_clock.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/common/thread.hpp:41,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/concurrency/basic.hpp:31,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/config/core.hpp:35,
                 from /root/websocketpp-experimental/websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp:31,
                 from broadcast_server.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:270:12: error: declaration of 'struct std::owner_less<boost::weak_ptr<void> >'
```

**how i installed (dependencies, actual program, etc)**

https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/wiki/Setup-0.3X-on-Ubuntu-12.10

**alternatives welcome**

If anyone has alternatives to `std::owner_less`, please post them.

Comment: try #include <memory>

Comment: @SamMiller Thank-you for looking!  plz c edit

Comment: Add key `-std=c++11` to compiler's command line

Comment: @borisbn woah, i just got WAY more errors lol.  Thank you for looking tho!

Comment: post the errors, you need c++11 to use std::owner_less

Comment: @SamMiller i exceeded the limit, so i posted until it mentions the `std::owner_less`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::owner_less is a C++11 STL feature that allows you to put std::weak_ptr in associative containers like set and map. Ultimately, connection_hdl is a weak_ptr, and that is why it needs the custom comparison function.

WebSocket++ 0.3.x can be configured via preprocessor defines to use either C++03 + Boost or C++11. By default it uses C++03 + Boost. Boost weak_ptr works a little differently and does not need a custom comparison function. If you use a list, queue, or vector it is also unnecessary since those containers do not use the connection_hdl as keys.

Most of the examples in the 0.3.x manual and bundled with the library use C++11 because it is a lot more clean and concise. To compile and link those examples as is you will need a C++11 compiler and to use the appropriate C++11 compiler flags and WebSocket++ defines. Scons is the build system that I use to automate building & running all of the examples and unit tests. It is not necessary to build and run individual example programs. Any other build system should work fine, as will feeding compiler arguments ad hoc on the command line.

I've set up a page in the manual that describes the various options for enabling/disabling C++11 features. http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/reference/cpp11-support. This manual page has a list of recommended compiler flags for the Operating systems and compilers I use most for testing.

For g++ 4.7 on Linux I would recommend: "-std=c++0x -D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_
-D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system". This enables all C++11 features except the  library (which is broken/buggy), and brings in the Boost version instead.

Comment: Thank you zaphoyd!  Your lib and support are the best I've ever experienced!

Comment: First I would also like to thank you for great library and documentation!

However, I also had this particular problem. I am hacking together a chat server with your library, and completely missed that the D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ define is necessary for using std::owner_less. I might not have read the documentation carefully enough but it would maybe be good to clarify this in the particular example.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the [documentation](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/wiki/Building-the-examples-and-unit-tests), I think you need to define `BOOST_ROOT_CPP11` when building.

> Similar to BOOST_ROOT but allows linking to a separate version of
>   Boost compiled against a C++11 STL

I based this on the following [header](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/websocketpp/common/memory.hpp)

```
#ifdef _WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_MEMORY_
    using std::shared_ptr;
    using std::weak_ptr;
    using std::enable_shared_from_this;
    using std::static_pointer_cast;

    typedef std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> unique_ptr_uchar_array;
#else
    using boost::shared_ptr;
    using boost::weak_ptr;
    using boost::enable_shared_from_this;
    using boost::static_pointer_cast;

    typedef boost::scoped_array<unsigned char> unique_ptr_uchar_array;
#endif
```

Which should use `std::weak_ptr` instead of `boost::weak_ptr`

---

If you'd like to use an alternate container instead of `std::set`, modify the example similar to this pseudo code

```
         if (a.type == SUBSCRIBE) {
                boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_connection_lock);
                m_connections.push_back(a.hdl);
            } else if (a.type == UNSUBSCRIBE) {
                boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_connection_lock);
                m_connections.erase(std::remove(m_connections.begin(), m_connections.end(), a.hdl));
            } else if (a.type == MESSAGE) {
                boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(m_connection_lock);

                con_list::iterator it;
                for (it = m_connections.begin(); it != m_connections.end(); ++it) {
                    m_server.send(*it,a.msg);
                }
            } else {
                // undefined.
            }
        }
    }
private:
    typedef std::deque<connection_hdl> con_list;
```

Which will use `std::deque` instead of `std::set`. The ordering will not be used, but for what I can tell that isn't needed in this example.