# how to export linker options?

Tags: c++, bash, linker, g++, export

I'm almost certain this is a dupe, but I don't have even the base vocabulary to begin researching this question.

I have a few `g++` linker flags that I'd like to make permanent as `export` variables in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Is it possible to do this for `-D_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_STL_ -D_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_CPP11_REGEX_ -lboost_regex -lboost_system` as in this answer for websocket++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/15469310/1382306 and `-lmysqlcppconn` for mysql connector c++ https://stackoverflow.com/a/11879650/1382306?

If so, please show me how.  If not, please show me how to get started.

Comment: Are you using `make` to compile, or just calling `g++` directly?

Comment: @teppic `g++` directly.  Thank your for looking!

Comment: Ah, as for `make` you can just set `LDFLAGS`. An option would be to create a bash function or alias to include an environment variable that does the same thing.

Comment: @teppic Thank you!  I will look into that.  This is for pure laziness's sake.  Would you mind expanding just a little to full answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `make` instead,  there are various standard environment variables that are sent to the compiler. One is `LDFLAGS`, so for example:

```
$ export LDFLAGS='-Wl,--print-map'
$ make foo.cpp
g++   -Wl,--print-map  foo.cpp   -o foo      // default rule
[...]
```

Linker flags have to be passed separated by commas after `-Wl`.

Alternatively, you could make an alias or shell function to call `g++` with an appropriate environment variable.